# mutualTLS with SpringBoot SslBundles and RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate, mutual-authentication

I have a SpringBoot Application (client) that makes REST calls to an external service (server). The communication between client and server should be secured with mutual TLS. So in this setting we need a client certificate in our keystore and a CA certificate for the server in our truststore.

When I importe this certificate material in Postman, i can successfully make requests. Meaning: the certificates are valid.

Nevertheless so far, I couldn't make it work in SpringBoot. I'd like to take advantage of the SslBundles introduced by SpringBoot 3.1

I defined a bundle with both keystore and truststore:

```yaml
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      jks:
        mySslBundle:
          keystore:
            location: "classpath:path/to/clientCert.p12"
            password: "PW"
            type: "PKCS12"
          truststore:
            location: "classpath:path/to/serverCA.p12"
            password: "PW"
            type: "PKCS12"
```

then I can bind this bundle to the RestTemplate:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

  @Bean(name = "fooRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate createFooRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,
      SslBundles sslBundles) {
    return restTemplateBuilder
        .setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("mySslBundle"))
        .build();
  }

}
```

When the client sends request to the server within the application, I get following error:

```
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

In Postman, i had to load the server cert as .pem file.
In my SpringBoot app, i converted the .pem file into a .p12 with openssl. I did that so that both client cert and server cert are p12 file and can be imported in the same sslBunde. Is this the right approach to import keystore and trustore in the same bundle ?

Any clue appreciated.

Comment: Postman (normally) ignores server cert errors so the fact you can do a request in postman doesn't mean it's correct. Try `keytool -list -keystore serverCA.p12` and see if it _shows_ the correct cert(s). If not make sure the p12 is created using Java (usually keytool) -- Java uses a special bag attribute for trusted certs that other software doesn't support.

Comment: Postman let you choose in the settings if the server cert should be validated or not. In my case I activated the validation. But you may have a point with the p12 file. In Postman i loaded the server cert as .pem. In my SpringBoot app, i had to convert the .pem into a .p12. with openssl, so that i can have the client cert and the server cert in the same sslBundle. Maybe something wrent wrong in this process.

Comment: If you mean something like `openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert(s).pem -nokeys -out some.p12` that does not create the bag attribute I described and thus will not be treated by Java as a trustedcert.

Answer (score 0):

as it was suggested in the comments, using keytool instead of openssl for the conversion of the .crt server cert into a .p12 solved my problem.

So, yes it is ok to pack keystore and trustore in the same bundle as i did, and we should use keytool if a conversion is needed to produce the .p12 file.